# Googlefinance no longer identifying OTC stocks as it had in the past

Tags: google-sheets, finance, stock, google-finance

I have a sheet that tracks the prices of several stocks using the Googlefinance function. It had been working for several months, but just recently started breaking with any companies listed on the OTC markets.

I've tried using OTCMKTS: before the ticker, and also using the Canadian exchange tickers but with no success.

The sheet had been working previously with the OTC tickers without any prefix, but now I cannot get them to work with the OTCMKTS: prefix or without.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10mKWy4kiWFoBdiQI1bQznqKYywyIYdsJld6pEyh6pns/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried using the various prefixes to identify specific exchanges such as OTCMKTS: and CNSX:, but nothing has fixed the issue. Previously, the sheet had been working with just the OTC ticker and no prefix specifying the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the ticker changes. For example I had the stock NVTA on NASDAQ (or NYSE, can't remember which) and now the stock exchange is OTC Markets Group so the ticker changed from NVTA to NVTAQ.

Basically now, to get its price, I have:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("OTCMKTS:NVTAQ", "price")
```

Go to https://www.google.com/finance/ and search for your stock and see if the ticker changed. But the OTCMKTS exchange prefix still works for me.